# How to check Rabbitmq readiness (Init Container)?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to implement a init container to check the readiness of my RabbiMQ cluster like this:

```
initContainers:
      - name: check-rabbitmq
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c',
        'until wget http://user:pass@rabbitmq0.rabbitmq.rabbits.svc.cluster.local:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F;
        do echo waiting; sleep 2; done;']
```

But my container is failing (ClashLoopBackOff) when I run wget like above and keeps waiting as if rabbimq wasn't running when I run the wget command like this:

```
['sh', '-c', 'until wget http://rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq.rabbits.svc.cluster.local:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F;
do echo waiting; sleep 2; done;']
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? This is the dns of my cluster: **rabbitmq0.rabbitmq.rabbits.svc.cluster.local**

Answer (score 0):

I worked like this:

```
 initContainers:
      - name: check-rabbitmq
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c',
        'until wget http://user:pass@rabbitmq:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F;
        do echo waiting; sleep 2; done;']
```

I actually had to pass the credentials and name of the service, which in my case was rabbitmq and NOT the DNS of the cluster.